# tkinter class composition not working

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, tkinter

My intention is to create gui from several classes and as exercise I created small example. As can be seen in app self.greet should be button created from class Button, but what I get is generic button (without text and callback function). 
Any suggestions?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Button(ttk.Button):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.item = ttk.Button(parent, text="Greet", command=self.greet)

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

class App():

    def __init__(self, parent):        
        parent.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = ttk.Label(parent, text="A label")
        self.greet = Button(parent)
        self.button = ttk.Button(parent, text="Close", command=parent.quit)

        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))
        self.greet.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.W, tk.E))

        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are using _composition_ then you shouldn't be inheriting from `ttk.Button`. Your class actually creates two buttons.

Comment: Well it's true that I'm learning about concepts so I can be and I am wrong about things. Regarding your comment if I don't inherit from `ttk.Button` like `class Button():` I get `builtins.TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new class *is* a Button, it does not need to contain a Button.

```
class FlebasButton(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")
```

Also, pick a name other than "Button" for your new class so that you (and others) don't confuse it with the class from tk. And tkinter uses "master" internally for the parent class, so it's generally better to use "master" as well for tkinter objects.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of your class `Button` are indeed just generic buttons with no text or callback.  Each one *contains* (via their `self.item` attribute) a fancier button, but that button is never actually visible to the user because you never pack or grid it.

Basically, the parameters you're passing to the `ttk.Button()` call should instead be passed in the `super().__init__()` call, so that they affect the `Button` object itself.